# DELETE with SELECT sub-query gets stuck

Tags: mysql, subquery

The following delete statement causing mysql to stuck:

`DELETE FROM domains WHERE id IN (SELECT domain_id FROM domains_groups WHERE group_id = 9);`

While this statement, which does the same, works:

`DELETE FROM domains WHERE id IN (select id from (SELECT domain_id as id FROM domains_groups WHERE group_id = 9) a);`

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason has to do with the optimization of SQL queries.  Your first version is evaluating the subquery for each row -- although this has been fixed in more recent versions of MySQL.  The second version is creating a temporary table, so this goes much faster.

I would recommend using `exists` or `join`:

```
DELETE d FROM domains d
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM domains_groups dg WHERE dg.group_id = 9 AND dg.domain_id  = d.id);
```

Or:

```
DELETE d
    FROM domains d JOIN
         domaings_groups dg
         ON dg.group_id = 9 AND dg.domain_id  = d.id;
```

I would also recommend an index either `domain_groups(domain_id, group_id)` (for the above two versions) or `domain_groups(group_id, domain_id)` (for the `in` version).